# How many generations passed between Bhagiratha and Rama?

Tags: rama, bhagiratha

Is anything written about the lifespan of the kings who were Rama's ancestors (the Sūryavaṃśa / Ikṣvāku Dynasty) up until Bhagīratha?

Answer (score 1):

14 generations -

> *The son of Dilipa was Bhagiratha. The son of Bhagiratha was Kakustha whose son was Raghu from whom the royal line has since been named. The
> sons of Shri Raghu were known by the names of Pravriddha, Purushadaka,
> Kalmashapada and Soudasa. The son of Kalmashapada was Shankhana who
> rising to great power, by a curse, was destroyed wth his whole army.
> The mighty hero Sudarshana was the son of Shankhana and his son was
> Agnivarna and Agnivarna’s son was Shighraga. His son was named Meru,
> and Meru’s son was Prashusvara, and his son was the great Sage
> Ambarisha. The son of Ambarisha was the truthful Prince Nahusha, whose
> son was the virtuous Nabhaga. Nabhaga had two sons, Aja and Suvrata,
> and the son of Aja was the illustrious sovereign Dasaratha.*

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424087.html